# UDP how to recvfrom different ports at server side with binded port

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, bind

I have a problem on UDP socket port bind on receiving message from different client ports.
I am compiling a C++ utility to check (20K) ports of a Linux server.
I create client threads to send different ports of server by pthread_create.
At server side, I have to bind socket to certain port, so it can only recvfrom (select like blocked IO)only 1 port.
Can you give me some suggestions on UDP server to receive message from different ports?

Comment: Your question is confusing. The title says "different ports at server side", but the question says "different client ports". Which is it?

Comment: sorry, it means different client ports. the usage model can be: clients send packets to server from port 1/port 2/port 3, while server port is bond to port 1, so at server side I can only received message at port 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't specify a source address in recvfrom(), then it will receive from all remote addresses and ports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive packets on multiple ports, you must open multiple sockets and use something like `select()` to multiplex the I/O.  The Berkeley sockets API does not allow a socket to `bind()` to more than one address.

Comment: Per my understanding, I need to create some sockets (bind to different ports ) at server side, the select at server side to waiting for client side packet? thanks a lot.

Comment: Normally a server binds to just one port. However, if the machine has multiple IPs, you may need to bind a different socket to each IP with the same port. This is necessary so that you can send the reply from the same address the the client sent the request to.